# Little problem ploting edge with mesh, pgplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm ploting the function `z=1+|x²-y|` making

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
 \section{Introduction}

  \begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[axis on top,axis equal,axis lines=center,view={110}{20},xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,xmin=-1,xmax=1,zmax=5]
    \addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=20},thick] {1+abs(x^2-y)};
    \addplot3[mesh,draw=gray,very thin,smooth,samples=70] {1+abs(x^2-y)};
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 %\caption{Gr\'afica y curvas de nivel de $f(x,y)=y^2-x^2$.}
 \end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't like how looks the graphic at `z=1`. There is one way to mesh make `z=1` looks like contour lines? (no add contour lines at `z=1`)